# How do I populate one column only in an existing database with db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dont really want to destroy my database then re-create it and then re-run seed on all the fields, I just want to populate one field in an existing database. Is there a way of doing this with `rake db:seed`

Comment: open your rails console and do the update ......

Comment: Could you  be more specific? Is this rake db:update? If so how do I tell it to update just one column

Comment: No.. You want this update _temporary_  ?

Comment: No permanent update written to the database

Comment: well edit your seeds.rb for future. But now open your console `rails c` and do the update there.......

Comment: so how do I do that update?

Comment: lets say I have 500 entries to change. the field already exists. I just need to put random number in between 1 and 200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81109/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-sebastian-zeki).